# Switching "voice" when interacting with a Facebook page via the Android app?

Tags: facebook

Facebook's standard web interface on desktop (and also on mobile) browsers allows an admin of a Page to choose to "use Facebook" (or to perform "posting, commenting, and liking") either as that Page or as him/her self.  Is it possible to do the same from the Android app?

My "Facebook for Android" app is currently at v7.0.0.26.28 (and my "Pages Manager" app is at v1.10), and for the pages that I manage, I seem to be able to post only as the Page and not as myself.